# ArcGIS Online Dashboard not loading when using its API for Python

Tags: python, arcgis

I am trying to create a WebMap that will be used as a widget in an ArcGIS dashboard. I am doing this through the ArcGIS API for Python. I successfully created the dashboard, and I can see it in my content in ArcGIS online. However, when I click on the dashboard, nothing loads, and all I see is a blank screen.

I have the same problem whenever I try and create WebMaps with this API. When I click on the WebMap I just see a blank screen. However, I am able to resolve this by clicking on "Open in MapView Classic." Of course, there is no Open in Dashboard Classic Option, so I am stuck with this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
#Creating WebMap that will become a widget in the dashboard

from arcgis.mapping import WebMap

search = g.content.search(title, item_type="Feature Layer")
map = WebMap()
item = search[0]
map.add_layer(item)
props = {'title': title,
         'snippet': 'hwa',
         'tags': 'python',
         "renderer": "autocast",
         "field_name": "Threat",
         }
map.save(props)

g.content.search(title, item_type='Web Map')[0].share(everyone=True)
g.content.search(title, item_type='Feature Layer')[0].share(everyone=True)
g.content.search(title, item_type='CSV')[0].share(everyone=True)


#Creating Dashboard

from arcgis.apps.dashboard import Dashboard, add_column, add_row
dashboard = Dashboard()
dashboard.layout = add_row(WebMap (map))
dashboard.save("Sample Dashboard")

g.content.search(query="title:Sample Dashboard1", item_type='Dashboard') 
[0].share(everyone=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might come a bit late, but I just had the same issue. Basically, you need to create a row AND a column within that row (or the other way around).